# Conflict making custom WordPress theme with my own header loading function

Tags: php, function, wordpress-theming

I have an issue that I have been working on for a while I can't wrap my head around it.
I read the documentation to make a WordPress theme and it says that you can customize the header, and footer files of the theme which is what I'm trying to do.

I have the header I want to use in a php function elsewhere in the directory. Yo are able to just have a php file with the following:

```
<?php define('IN_MAIN_SITE', true);

$bhw_root_path = '../../../../';

$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);

include($bhw_root_path . 'include/common.php');

page_header('', false, $page_title, $page_title, true); ?>
```

And this will display the header which applies all the css styles to the document. My logic was that if I could load this into the header file, then this would apply to all the WordPress pages and solve my problems. The issue is that the templates come up empty when I open it. Is there some conflict between my function and the WordPress functions? I know I'm referencing my function well because I tried to load my function in another php file in the same directory without any issues. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It completely had the wrong approach. I though I had to modify the header file, but this is only if you want to tweak WordPress' header. To use your own header generating function you have to make a call to it in each template file (index.php, single.php, etc.).